# Why there is no constructor-with-parameters constrain on generic parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, language-design

As we all know, we cannot write code like this in current version of C#:

```
public class A {
    public static void Method<T> () where T : new(string, string) {
        var x = new T("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

but we may use `new()` constrain to enforce that `T` has public parameter-less constructor, and then we are able to create new instances of `T` using `new T()` expression.

There is plenty of answers on SO about various workaround, but non of them explains why language designers not implemented such feature. From amount of questions on SO it looks like it would be useful in read world applications.

Why this feature was not implemented in C#, are there any chances that it will be added in next version of the language?

Comment: Exactly to whom are you addressing this question?  "Why" sort of questions such as this are a poor fit for SO.

Comment: It kind of defeats the purpose of being generic, as now your generic code has to know a little too much about the type. For the same reason you can't have constructors in an interface, constructors are an implementation detail.

Comment: [*I am asked “why doesn’t C# implement feature X?” all the time. The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature.*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods)

Comment: [Here is a link to the proposal on github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2206). Seems to be a CLR limitation.

Comment: @PetSerAI of course this is one of the generic answers, but on SO there is this amazing community that have people like Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert, people that are involved in _designing_ the language, and they may share some insight why this feature was not implemented. It may not only be the case that it is costly, maybe it will introduce some inconsistency int the type system.

Comment: @Jesse Good - thanks for the link, there are some valuable insights like resolving constructor overloading at runtime

Comment: @csharpfolk: Yeah, based on the comments in the link, I highly doubt we will see this feature in C# 7 (or even 8 :) ).

Comment: The core problem is that there is no way to identify the specific constructor method that needs to be called when the generic class is compiled.  Code like this can only be *efficient* in a template-based approach, very much not the way .NET generics were implemented.  Only other alternative is to use Reflection at runtime, very much not what .NET generics were meant to do.  If you want to write slow code then you have to be explicit about it so it is obvious to anybody, calling Activator.CreateInstance() is up to you.

Comment: @Hans Passant from what I know `new T()` is implemented using `Activator.CreateInstance()`. CIL generated for `new T()` is `call !!0 class [mscorlib]System.Activator::CreateInstance<!!0>()`

Comment: Yes, it is micro-optimized in the CLR.  Note that it can't take arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [feature request link on github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2206), the reason is that the CLR doesn't provide the information that C# needs to implement it.

There is speculation that the CLR may be modified in order for a future C# version (7.0?) to support this feature.